# Magento 1.9x - Include Dataflow Profile Functionality for Import operation into my custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, import, dataflow

I have created custom module for import operation by uploading csv, xls and ods files. It is working good, but now i need to include **Dataflow Profile** Functionality into my module.

That means I have a button in the page when i click that button is should do the operation like as **Run Profile in Popup** button (kindly look at the below pictures)

[image]

[image]

no need to override the GuiController or ProfileController
i just need functions of them in my module..

kindly share your suggestions.

Comment: I asked the same question a while ago, be interested to see if someone answers yours: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117283/magento-1-how-to-use-the-dataflow-import-view-with-a-custom-import

Comment: ya i was search for this, but i didtn't get your question...thanks for commenting

Comment: have you got any ideas to do?

Comment: No I never came back to that unfortunately, it's still on hold ^^

Comment: ok thank you...

Comment: Why do you want to use this functionality? How about using `Ho_Import` or `Avs_FastSimpleImport`?

Comment: If the extension is "distributable", you'll need to create a new profile via your setup script. Take example from how Magento generates default profiles. After that, you'll need to create 1 adaptor and 1 parser in your extension for import & export respectively, have them extend the default classes so you don't have to write everything from scratch.